# How to solve Application is not registered in our store. error while using GRAPH API for making a call?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, graph-api, beta

I am trying to make a call in one of the channels in MS Teams via Postman.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the below article. I have also given all the required permission.

[Create Call to Teams using GRAPH API - BETA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

I am able to successfully retrieve other beta APIs but with `/beta/app/calls` I am getting **the Application is not registered in our store** error.

Initially, I got **Unsupported AAD Identity** error but, that I solved as per the steps mentioned in the below reference.

[Solve Unsupported AAD Identity Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123650/how-to-fix-unsupported-aad-identity-when-create-a-call-from-webapp)

**Note: I tried to make the call from SPFx web part but over there also I am getting the same error.**

My main goal is to make a call to channel of the team and all the members should get the notification for the same. (Same as meet now button's functionality in teams app)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by generating an access token without user as mentioned  [Get access without a user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) and passed it in the authorization.

Comment: The downvote is appreciated. It will be great if you let me know the reason for the same.

Comment: Hey! This has been a while... But I'm stuck at the same issue.
I can retrieve Users and their Graph information. But as soon as I try to get anything Teams related I keep getting "Application is not registered in our store.","instanceAnnotations".

Do you know how to fix this? I have all the rights with admin consent...

Comment: did you tried the solution I have mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Well, we created a Service Principal in Azure which I use to authenticate against `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenandID}`. So I guess that's what you did, correct?

Comment: Can you please try to generate the authentication token same as mentioned in the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service link?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. In C# though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register in azure app registrion portal

Following are the steps:

1. Register your app.
2. Configure permissions for Microsoft Graph on your app.
3. Get administrator consent.
4. Get an access token.
5. Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph.

Need to use "application ID" and Client "secret key" for authorization.
Need to set permision to use Microsoft graph API (Like read , write permission).
Then grant admin consent permissions for accesing api.
A token is generated for authentication based on above configurations.

Reference link : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/