# Microsoft Graph Call API Error - Application is not registered in our store

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, error, microsoft-graph, microsoft

I am using Postman to run Microsoft Graph REST API for making outbound call similar to yours.

I have followed steps as suggested in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service but still getting below error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "UnknownError",
      "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"7503\",\"message\":\"Application is not registered in our store.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
      "innerError": {
         "request-id": "33454-0d79-45cd-acde-e31d5ad6665f",
         "date": "2020-02-20T05:36:28"
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason? I have given all Calls related permission to as Application Permission.

When I decoding my token on `jwt.io` , I can see my app id and roles/permissions are there which I configured.

This Question is similar to [How to solve Application is not registered in our store. error while using GRAPH API for making a call?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271151/how-to-solve-application-is-not-registered-in-our-store-error-while-using-graph).

Regards,
Umesh